# Match bullet numbers with regex using python

Tags: python, regex

I am extracting questions from a word document. The questions in the word document are bullet numbered like below:

```
1.) Gauri Khanna, who was born on September ........  
2.) Rohit Arora was born on October 10, 1987.......
```

And the answer options are bullet numbered like below:

```
  a) First option
  b) Second option
  b) Third option
  c) Forth option
```

I would like two regular expressions to extract questions and their possible options.

What I have tried so far on the questions.

```
(\d\.\))+ #this only matches the first occurrence
```

I am a dummy when it comes to regular expressions and searches on google and stack overflow did not help me. Thank you

Comment: you want to match: `Gauri Khanna, who was born on September ........  ` from he first option, and `Rohit Arora was born on October 10, 1987.......` from the second?

Comment: It's not entirely clear how the input string and expected output string(s) look like. Do the options always follow immediately after a question? Are they in two separate files/strings?

Comment: @pivanchy The is a bunch of text in the document, but I would like when the regular expression sees 1.), it returns the text. In the first case it would return "Gauri Khanna, who was born on September ........  "

For the second option it would encounter "c)" and return "Forth option"

Comment: @timgeb Their could be other paragraphs before or after the question. It is guaranteed that the options will always immediately follow a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for extracting questions.

```
r'[0-9]\..+'
```

And for Answers.

```
r'[a-z].+'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Hassan. Let me try this and get back to you

Comment: Okk sure!
If you need any help, just comment here and I will help you out :)

Comment: This is how I used your solution. I had to modify a little and then use split method. so for questions:
I used re.compile("[0-9]\.\)").split(myString)

And for Answers: re.compile("[a-z]\)").split(myString)

Comment: Thank you very much. Will definitely reach out if i need help.